# Rewrite rules to redirect alias domain to main domain and path not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect requests for an alias domain to a particular path on the main domain, I'm not getting any errors, but the redirect is not working. I'm thinking that something else is redirecting after the initial rule.

here is the .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# these are the rules that are not working
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.alias-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.com/path/path/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# The Friendly URLs part
# detect language when requesting the root (/)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^org [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ fr/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|org)/favicon.ico$ favicon.ico [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|org)/assets(.*)$ assets$2 [L,QSA]

# to index.php and set the cultureKey parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|org)?/?(.*)$ index.php?cultureKey=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]
```

anyone know why the alias-domain is not redirecting to the domain?

**UPDATE**
As requested ~ vhost.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    <VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:443 >
        ServerName "domaindomain.com:443"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.com"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.com"
        ServerAlias "factorsusa.com"
        ServerAlias "www.factorsusa.com"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.factorsusa.com"
        ServerAlias "factorscanada.com"
        ServerAlias "www.factorscanada.com"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.factorscanada.com"
        ServerAlias "factorscanada.ca"
        ServerAlias "www.factorscanada.ca"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.factorscanada.ca"
        ServerAlias "domaindomain.ca"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.ca"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.ca"
        ServerAlias "domaincredit.com"
        ServerAlias "www.domaincredit.com"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaincredit.com"
        ServerAlias "domaindomain.co"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.co"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.co"
        ServerAlias "domaindomainltd.com"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomainltd.com"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomainltd.com"
        ServerAlias "domaindomainltd.ca"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomainltd.ca"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomainltd.ca"
        ServerAlias "domaindomain.ca"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.ca"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.ca"
        ServerAlias "domaindomain.co"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.co"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.co"
        ServerAlias "domaindomain.com"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.com"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.com"
        ServerAlias "domaindomain.net"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.net"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.net"
        ServerAlias "domaindomain.lease"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.lease"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.lease"
        ServerAlias "domaindomainus.com"
        ServerAlias "www.domaindomainus.com"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomainus.com"
        ServerAdmin "rowens@domaindomain.com"
        UseCanonicalName Off

        DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/httpdocs"
        CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/system/domaindomain.com/logs/access_ssl_log plesklog
        ErrorLog "/var/www/vhosts/system/domaindomain.com/logs/error_log"

        <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
            SuexecUserGroup "domain" "psacln"
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
            UserDir "/var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/web_users"
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_sysenv.c>
            SetSysEnv PP_VHOST_ID ""
        </IfModule>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLVerifyClient none
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-C
        SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-q
        SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/system/domaindomain.com/etc/php.ini
        SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_CGI_INDEX module

        <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
            FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/system/domaindomain.com/etc/php.ini
            FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_CGI_INDEX module
            FcgidMaxRequestLen 13421
        </IfModule>

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/httpdocs>

            <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
                php_admin_flag engine on
            </IfModule>

            <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                php_admin_flag engine on
            </IfModule>

            SSLRequireSSL

            Options -Includes -ExecCGI

        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/web_users>

            <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
                php_admin_flag engine off
            </IfModule>

            <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                php_admin_flag engine off
            </IfModule>

        </Directory>

        Alias /error_docs /var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/error_docs
        ErrorDocument 400 /error_docs/bad_request.html
        ErrorDocument 401 /error_docs/unauthorized.html
        ErrorDocument 403 /error_docs/forbidden.html
        ErrorDocument 404 /error_docs/not_found.html
        ErrorDocument 500 /error_docs/internal_server_error.html
        ErrorDocument 405 /error_docs/method_not_allowed.html
        ErrorDocument 406 /error_docs/not_acceptable.html
        ErrorDocument 407 /error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html
        ErrorDocument 412 /error_docs/precondition_failed.html
        ErrorDocument 414 /error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html
        ErrorDocument 415 /error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html
        ErrorDocument 501 /error_docs/not_implemented.html
        ErrorDocument 502 /error_docs/bad_gateway.html
        ErrorDocument 503 /error_docs/maintenance.html

        <IfModule mod_security2.c>
        </IfModule>

    </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>

<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80 >
    ServerName "domain.com:80"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.com"
    ServerAlias "factorsusa.com"
    ServerAlias "www.factorsusa.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.factorsusa.com"
    ServerAlias "factorscanada.com"
    ServerAlias "www.factorscanada.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.factorscanada.com"
    ServerAlias "factorscanada.ca"
    ServerAlias "www.factorscanada.ca"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.factorscanada.ca"
    ServerAlias "domaindomain.ca"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.ca"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.ca"
    ServerAlias "domaincredit.com"
    ServerAlias "www.domaincredit.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaincredit.com"
    ServerAlias "domaindomain.co"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.co"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.co"
    ServerAlias "domaindomainltd.com"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomainltd.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomainltd.com"
    ServerAlias "domaindomainltd.ca"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomainltd.ca"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomainltd.ca"
    ServerAlias "domaindomain.ca"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.ca"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.ca"
    ServerAlias "domaindomain.co"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.co"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.co"
    ServerAlias "domaindomain.com"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.com"
    ServerAlias "domaindomain.net"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.net"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.net"
    ServerAlias "domaindomain.lease"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomain.lease"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomain.lease"
    ServerAlias "domaindomainus.com"
    ServerAlias "www.domaindomainus.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.domaindomainus.com"
    ServerAdmin "rowens@domaindomain.com"
    UseCanonicalName Off

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/httpdocs"
    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/system/domaindomain.com/logs/access_log plesklog
    ErrorLog "/var/www/vhosts/system/domaindomain.com/logs/error_log"

    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup "domain" "psacln"
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir "/var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/web_users"
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_sysenv.c>
        SetSysEnv PP_VHOST_ID ""
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine off
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/system/domaindomain.com/etc/php.ini
    SetEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_CGI_INDEX module

    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/system/domaindomain.com/etc/php.ini
        FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_CGI_INDEX module
        FcgidMaxRequestLen 1342
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/httpdocs>

        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
            php_admin_flag engine on
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_flag engine on
        </IfModule>

        Options -Includes -ExecCGI

    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/web_users>

        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
            php_admin_flag engine off
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_flag engine off
        </IfModule>

    </Directory>

    Alias /error_docs /var/www/vhosts/domaindomain.com/error_docs
    ErrorDocument 400 /error_docs/bad_request.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /error_docs/unauthorized.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /error_docs/forbidden.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /error_docs/not_found.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /error_docs/internal_server_error.html
    ErrorDocument 405 /error_docs/method_not_allowed.html
    ErrorDocument 406 /error_docs/not_acceptable.html
    ErrorDocument 407 /error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html
    ErrorDocument 412 /error_docs/precondition_failed.html
    ErrorDocument 414 /error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html
    ErrorDocument 415 /error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html
    ErrorDocument 501 /error_docs/not_implemented.html
    ErrorDocument 502 /error_docs/bad_gateway.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /error_docs/maintenance.html

    Include "/var/www/vhosts/system/domaindomain.com/conf/vhost.conf"

    <IfModule mod_security2.c>
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you add the alias domain as a server alias in the conf file and change DNS to point to your server IP for the alias domain?

Comment: The domain is added as an alias & I have my local hosts file pointing my DNS.

Comment: just the domain or the www also? what are you typing in. Can you show your vhost config for that?

Comment: it should be both domain-alias.com & www.domain-alias.com that redirect/

Comment: Can you post your vhost config? Also your current rules will only redirect www.

Comment: nothing exciting in the vhost config - some php stuff, nothing that is redirecting or setting specific directory rules both aliases are listed in the vhost as well.

Comment: the current rules do not redirect at all. niether www.domain-alias or domain-alias posted vhost anyway ...

Comment: BTW you can list your alias' on one line to shorten your conf. e.g. `ServerAlias example.com *.example.com domain2.com www.domain2.com` Also your local host file has both entries I would assume? I don't see why it shouldn't work. however the top rule should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alias-domain\.com$ [NC]` for both www and non www matching.

Comment: the vhost file is autogenerated by plesk, so it's really not easily modified - or really worth the effort either....

Comment: hmmm  actually it appears my browser was caching the redirect? seems to be working now.